# Change content dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the HTML content off a `div` based on a click function. The problem is that my script prints the name instead of the HTML content. Any ideas?

This is what I have so far:

```
var fragment_1 = $('#fragment_1').html();
var fragment_2 = $('#fragment_2').html();
var fragment_3 = $('#fragment_3').html();
var counter = 1;

$("#main").html(fragment_1);

$("#videre").click(stageChange);

function stageChange(){

    counter ++;

    $("#main").html('fragment_' + counter);

};
```

Comment: That HTML should be stored in an array instead. Would make accessing it a lot easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
var i,
  count = 3,
  prefix = 'fragment_',
  fragmentMap = {},
  counter = 1;

for ( i = count; i > 0; i-- ) {
  fragmentMap[ i ] = $( '#'+ prefix + i ).html();
}

$("#main").html(fragmentMap[ counter ]);

$("#videre").click(stageChange);

function stageChange(){

    $("#main").html(fragmentMap[ ++counter ]);

};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reference your `fragment_` *n* variable through the `window` object (assuming those variables are global) by passing `'fragment_' + counter` in through square brackets:

```
$("#main").html(window['fragment_' + counter]);
```

This references the `fragment_` *n* variable belonging to `window`.

Comment: It seems to work well, but it breaks all my jquery depending code inside the #main div now.

Comment: @MikkelEmilLindblom Breaks *how*?